How to parse data of SOD (Security Object Document) extracted from ID Card by flutter_nfc_kit?
I have developed an android application to read data from ID Card using NFC, now i need to read  SOD (Security Object Document) information, i used the code bolow,
but i got this error
Encountered unsupported ASN.1 tag: UnsupportedASN1TagException: Tag 119 is not supported yet
_nfc.setIosAlertMessage(formatProgressMsg("Reading EF.SOD ...", 80)); // read ID Card data
mrtdData.sod = await passport.readEfSOD();

parseEfSOD(mrtdData.sod!.toBytes()); // parse data 

void parseEfSOD(Uint8List sodBytes) {
  // Parse the SOD bytes
  print("parse phase 1");
  ASN1Parser parser = ASN1Parser(sodBytes);
  print("parse phase 1.01");
  ASN1Sequence sodSequence = parser.nextObject() as ASN1Sequence; //<== something went wrong here (Tag 119 is not supported yet)
  
 print('data is parsed succefully');
}

how can i resolve this error ?
